# Acceder a la session del carrito - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas quiero acceder a las session del carrito, para poder almacernarlo en la bd pero todo el rato me devuelve error:

```
Undefined index: qty
```

Estoy probando de la siguiente manera:

```
public function transferencia(Request $request)
    {
        $cart = Session::get('cart');

            foreach ($cart as $data) {
                $qty = $data['qty'];
            }

    print_r($data);
    }
```

Si quito `$qty = $data['qty'];` para hacer el `print_r($data);` me devuelve esto:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [83a160638014435c01e47450d02cb8b6] => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem Object ( [rowId] => 83a160638014435c01e47450d02cb8b6 [id] => 20 [qty] => 1 [name] => Cama Hoppekids Basic con barrera de seguridad – pared [price] => 210 [weight] => 550 [options] => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [medida] => 70x160 [imagen] => /photos/1/productos/familiar.jpg [marca] => OLAF ) ) [taxRate] => 21 [associatedModel:Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem:private] => [discountRate:Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem:private] => 0 ) ) )
```

Es decir si recibo datos, no se porque no puedo acceder a ellos. Utilizo laravel 5.8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: vale muchas gracias @Cesarin

Comment: $data trae tu arreglo , para que lo puedas imprimir tienes que hacer un recorrido, tengo un ejemplo pero es muy diferente a tu código pero igual te lo pongo para que te des una idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera, como decia @Cesarin hay que recorrerlo.

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $order) {
                $data = json_decode($order, true); 
                foreach($data as $item){
                    $opt = new Order;
                    $opt->id_cliente = $request->input('idusuario');
                    $opt->fecha = date('j/n/Y');
                    $opt->cliente = $request->input('persona');
                    $opt->dni = $request->input('dni');
                    $opt->producto = $item['name'];
                    $opt->medida = 'medida';
                    $opt->marca = 'marca';
                    $opt->precio = number_format($item['price'], 2); 
                    $opt->cantidad = $item['qty'];
                    $opt->subtotal = number_format($item['subtotal'], 2); 
                    $opt->iva = number_format($item['tax'], 2); ;

                    $formateado = $item['subtotal'] + $item['tax'];

                    $opt->total = number_format($formateado, 2);
                    //$opt->factura = $idpedido .'.pdf';
                    $opt->idpedido = $idpedido;

                    $opt->metodo = $request->input('metodoPago');
                    
                    $opt->save();
                } 
                
            }
```

Pero no se como acceder a lo que esta dentro de `options`. Es decir quiero acceder a `Marca` y `Medida` pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

```html
              $contador_i=0;
                foreach ($resultado as $expeaux)
                {
              $this->area_expe->set_id_area_expe($expeaux['id_area_expe'],$contador_i);
              $this->area_expe->set_area_expe($expeaux['area_expe'],$contador_i);
              $this->area_expe->set_id_subarea_expe($expeaux['id_subarea_expe'],$contador_i);
               $contador_i++;
                }
```

la idea en este ejemplo se recorre el arreglo iniciando con cero y así, hasta que termina el arreglo termina el recorrido, asignando los valores que encuentra en el registro. tendrás que adecuar a Laravel

Por no dejar te pongo la referencia de PHP para foreach conviene darle una leída a los ejemplos para ayudarse a entender que hace el foreach.

[Manual PHP para foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias reviso tu idea @Cesarin

Comment: @Miguel a veces es complicado el manejo de arreglos y veo que el tuyo tiene otro arreglo dentro, espero te sirva de algo lo que publique.

Comment: @BetaM La intencion es que vea dos maneras diferentes de hacer las cosas, y en lo personal me da mucho trabajo editar sobre una respuesta ya me ha pasado que me quedan "mochas" y termino por borrar todo...

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de acceder a los datos que trae una consulta es hacer algo como esto, realizas tu select, obtienes el resultado `$resultado= $this->consultaSelect($consulta);` ... en la misma consulta haces una lista de los elementos que tienes en la tabla

```html
$contador = 0;
        while ($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            
$listaBienes[$contador] = new bienes(); // instancia a la clase
$listaBienes[$contador]->setEnteroId_Bien(utf8_encode($registro['ID_BIEN']));
$listaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaFabricante(utf8_encode($registro['FABRICANTE']));
$listaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaMarca(utf8_encode($registro['MARCA']));
$listaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaModelo(utf8_encode($registro['MODELO']));
$listaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaMaterial(utf8_encode($registro['MATERIAL']));
$listaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaColor(utf8_encode($registro['COLOR']));
$listaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaTipo(utf8_encode($registro['TIPO']));
$contador++;
        }
        return $listaBienes;
```

y en el HTML los obtienes para llevarlos a una tabla o vista

```html
<body>
<?php
   for($i=0; $i<$totalResultadoBienes; $i++){
                                    
                                    $marca=$resultadoBienes[$i]->getCadenaMarca();
                                    $modelo=$resultadoBienes[$i]->getCadenaModelo();
                                    $material=$resultadoBienes[$i]->getCadenaMaterial();
                                    $color=$resultadoBienes[$i]->getCadenaColor();
}
?>
</body>
```

y ya de aquí los puedes imprimir, poner en una tabla, en un input, en un modal, etc etc etc.

Saludos